# whenever cron is not working with rails-3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, whenever

I'm using **Whenever** for the first time. My cron is not working on the production server.

I m using rails-3.1.2

**In my schedule.rb file**

```
every :hour do # Many shortcuts available: :hour, :day, :month, :year, :reboot
  runner "Report.create_report", :environment=>"development"
end

every 2.minutes do
    runner "Report.create_report2" , :environment=>"development"
end
```

**In my Report model file**

```
  def self.create_report
    r = Report.new
    r.ad_network_campaign_id =1
    r.ad_network_campaign_name=2
    r.save
  end

  def self.create_report2
    r = Report.new
    r.ad_network_campaign_id =5
    r.ad_network_campaign_name=5
    r.save
  end
```

**After this I run the command**

```
whenever --update-crontab <project_name>
```

**In my crontab**

```
crontab -l
# Begin Whenever generated tasks for: project_name
0 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /var/www/jigserv && script/rails runner -e production '\''Report.create_report'\'''

0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38,40,42,44,46,48,50,52,54,56,58 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /var/www/jigserv && script/rails runner -e production '\''Report.create_report2'\'''

# End Whenever generated tasks for: project_name
```

In the last my data is not inserted in the Report table as I want.

Answer (score 0):

Dude, its complete off the topic but there are lot of issues using `whenever` in Rails 3. I would recommend you to migrate to [Resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque). It is dead simple and less hassle than `whenever`. And here is [resque-scheduler](https://github.com/bvandenbos/resque-scheduler) for same. [Here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/271-resque) is a railscasts that should get you started.